# url rewriting problems php

Tags: php, html, url, url-rewriting

I'm asking about url rewriting

I have a search result of e.g AdminJob at xxxxxx. So naturally I would like to have a url `/job-search.php/AdminJob` at xxxxxx but the problem is that spaces will cause url links to have a problem.

Therefore is there a workaround or could I have the id posted `job-search.php?ads=13` instead?

If I do the latter, there is one problem, how do I, based on the `ads=13`, call the data from the database, return with `AdminJob at xxxxxx`and change the url to `/job-search.php/AdminJob-at-xxxxxx`

**Updated**

What I have now `/job-search.php?ads=10&name=Test-One`

What I want to achieve  `/job-search.php/Test-one`

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^job-search/(.*) job-search.php?ads=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

`job-search.php?ads=13` is equal to `job-search/13`

regarding how to create the link since you have the name from the database you just do that

```
<a href='<?php echo urlencode($row['name']); ?>' />
```

or

```
echo "<a href='". urlencode($row[name]) ."' />";
```

on the job-search.php use `urldecode($_GET['name']);`

Comment: HI Thanks for the respond but the problem is that i want to use the 13 to retrieve from database and rewrite the url is that possible ?

Comment: For example you have 2 divs each one contain a name for the job which is clickable you want to make the link inside the a tag like this job-search/jobid am i right?

Comment: i think i will change the format abit

/job-search.php?ads=10&name=Test-one 
change to 
/job-search.php/Test-one

Comment: you will include both the name and the id in the url? or just the name? it's your choice i think a job name wouldn't be much long 

i updated the answer regarding how to create the link adding both will be more good cause job title may repeat twice which will cause displaying errors

Comment: Thanks but i think u misunderstood me but thanks for the effort